# Putting a div inside an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in a confusing situation. I have a div like this

```
<div class="editable" id="{{ $company->id }}" data-attribute="description">
                    {{ $company->description }}
</div>
```

I am actually using `jinplace` inediting and it requires a div to set up like above. I am looking for a way to use character count on this, which only works on `input` type elements

I tried setting it up like this

```
 <div class="editable" id="{{ $company->id }}" data-attribute="description">
  <input type="text" data-length="500" value="{{ $company->description }}"
    </div>
```

It shows the character count for this div, but when submitting does not update.

Any ideas how I can set this up?

Comment: Can you provide more context or an example? Also your input doesn't have a `name` attribute which you will probably need if your submitting the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jinplace` doest use standard forms for data it uses AJAX see [here](https://bitbucket.org/itinken/jinplace/wiki/Data) also it doesn't use a data-length attribute see [here](https://bitbucket.org/itinken/jinplace/wiki/Attributes).

Instead I would use some jQuery as you are already using that in your project given `jinplace` is a jQuery plugin.

Using the standard [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) attribute you can turn simply turn any element into editable.

Then I would use a counter to update a hidden field so you can post the data to a server in the standard way.

```js
$(function () {
  countDiv("#companyId");
});

function countDiv(sender) {
  var html = $(sender).html();
  var count = html.length;
  var maxCount = $(sender).data("count");
  
  if (count > maxCount) {
    html = html.substring(0, maxCount);
    $("#companyId").html(html);
    count = maxCount;
  }
  
  $("#companyIdCount").text(count);
  $("#hfCompanyId").text(html);
}

function test() {
  console.log($("#hfCompanyId").html());
}
```

```css
#companyId {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="hfCompanyId" name="hfCompanyId" />

<div contentEditable id="companyId" oninput="countDiv(this);" data-count="500">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a mollis magna. Sed quis iaculis nisl. Integer eget leo pulvinar, scelerisque ante nec, euismod lorem.
</div>

<br />

Count: <span id="companyIdCount"></span>

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" onclick="test();" value="Test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out a `contenteditable` div.

Here's how you can count the character length using Vanilla JS.

```js
var toCount     = document.getElementById('toCount'),
    charCount   = document.getElementById('charCount');
    
updateCount(toCount);

function updateCount(el) {
  charCount.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.length;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="toCount" oninput="updateCount(this)">This is an editable paragraph.</div>
<span id="charCount"></span> words
```